# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of undefined at HTMLDocument on the function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

in the console showing an error message on function that jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of undefined at HTMLDocument.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function change() {

        var form = this.form,
            Name_of_comp = form.elements.Name_of_comp,
            crr = $('.p1').hide(),
            icss = $('.p2').hide();


        if (Name_of_comp.value == 'Capacitor') {
            crr.show();

        } else
        if (Name_of_comp.value == 'Resistors') {

            crr.show();
        } else {
            icss.show();
            Name.value = ' ';
        }

    }

    var form = document.getElementById('add_name');
    form.elements.Name_of_comp.onchange = change;
    form.elements.Name_of_comp.onchange();
})
```

```html
>     front end  
<td><select class="form-control" onchange="change()" id="dropdown1" name="Name_of_comp[]">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="Capacitor">Capacitor</option>
                                    <option value="Resistors">Resistors</option>
                                    <option value="IC">IC's</option></select>
```

Comment: <td><select class="form-control select1"  name="Package[]"><option value="" class="p1">Select</option>
                         <option value="1206" class="p1">1206</option>
                                    <option value="0603" class="p1">0603</option>
                                    <option value="DIP" class="p1">DIP</option>

                                    <option value="" class="p2">Select</option>
                                    <option value="DIP" class="p2">DIP</option>
                                    <option value="SSOP" class="p2">SSOP</option></select>

Comment: you have select jquery library ad the beginning.

Comment: i have added olgun YILDIZ

Comment: Could you please add all your form?

Comment: i think this code is sufficient sir.